# Different behaviour between using "=[]" and ".clear()" to delete list content?

Tags: python, list

I have some Excel spreadsheet data that looks like:

```
key Book    Author  Price
1   Flowers Peter   11
2   Animals Paul    12
3   Trees   Mary    13
4   Cars    Otto    14
```

I tried to make a nested list from this data using `openpyxl`, like so:

```
import openpyxl as xls
rowList = []
comList = []
wb = xls.load_workbook('ExampleExcel.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

srow: int = ws.max_row
scol: int = ws.max_column

for x in range(1, srow+1):
    rowList.clear() # working alternative rowList = []
    for y in range(1, scol+1):
        rowList.append(ws.cell(row=x, column=y).value)
    comList.append(rowList)

print(comList )
```

When I use `rowList = []` to clear the list, I get the desired result:

```
[['key', 'Book', 'Author', 'Price'], [1, 'Flowers', 'Peter', 11], [2, 'Animals', 'Paul', 12], [3, 'Trees', 'Mary', 13], [4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14]]
```

But when I use `rowList.clear()`, I get a different result:

```
[[4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14], [4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14], [4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14], [4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14], [4, 'Cars', 'Otto', 14]]`
```

Why does the result change? What is wrong with the `.clear` version of the code?

Comment: To curators: "needs debugging details" is almost never an appropriate closure reason for a *conceptual* problem. Especially not if there is code. OP correctly identified a specific change to the code that causes a problem, and *specifically* asked about the *semantics* of each alternate version of the code. Any necessary debugging has already been done. The great thing about expecting people to debug their code before posting - which **was correctly done here** - is that it tends to isolate easily recognizable duplicate questions. Please instead look for those.

Comment: when you append list to other list then it doesn't duplicate values but it put only reference to original list. So when you use `clear` then `comlist` has 4 references to the same place in memory. When you use `[]` then it creates new place in memory and `comlist` has 4 different refenreces. Maybe run code on [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/) to vizualize it.

Comment: Hello Martin, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the linked duplicate to understand the difference between clearing out the content of a list (which `.clear` does) vs. reassigning a new list to the name (variable). This is a consequence of the fact that Python's names have *reference semantics*.

Comment: *Because* the version with `.clear` doesn't use a new list, the *same list object* is repeatedly added to `comList`. I added another duplicate link to explain that in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I still do not understand that I got after five run throughs (with clearing the "row" constructiong list after each run) five times the in the last run constructed list (the fith row in excel) in the collecting list.

Comment: Because the collecting list has **the same object in it**, remembered five times, and you repeatedly clear and re-fill that list. It is the same as if you use five different nicknames for your friend, and your friend puts on a hat, and you call out all those nicknames: every time, someone wearing a hat looks back at you. Coming up with the nickname did not create a new person.

Comment: You might want to read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: run code on [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/) to visualize it - you will see references as arrows. And `comList` will have 5 references to the same list `rowList` in memory. And when you put new data to `rowList` then 5 references shows the same data.

Comment: Ok, I got some understanding. But I have to let this to sink in a bit. Thanks. @Furas now I got it.